# How container name atribution works in docker

Tags: docker

I'm new docker learner, and could someone explain to me why whenever we start a new container it's give to us random names (and where they come from, it's the last column), as shown in the image bellow
[image]

Comment: Containers are given random names because names are often easier for people to remember than long hexadecimal ids. If you give your container an explicit name (with the `--name` option) then it won't get a random name.

Comment: The linked question describes both how the names are generated and how to assign your own, as @larsks suggests.  (Assigning a `docker run --name` is usually right.)